# Clustering Computation in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing

How can we the concept of clustering for computation in a node.js program. Say I have a computationally-intensive operation:

```
for(var i=0; i < 1000000; i++) {
   for(var u=0; u < 10000000; u++) { 
       calltofunction(i,u) {
            // some heavy computation
            return(some x)
       }
   }
}
```

The above currently uses only one core of my 4 core mac. How can I make it use multiple cores (or all) in order to make it faster?

Comment: Read api docs. https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Comment: calltofunction doesn't take a callback?

Comment: @Alex No, the call doesn't take a call back.